# How to fix notes in R package about mispelled words and example times

Tags: r, r-package

I am working on an R package that I recently pushed to CRAN. However, I got the following NOTEs which I guess forces CRAN to fail the package submission via its autocheck.

The first note was as follows:

> New submission
>
> Possibly misspelled words in DESCRIPTION:
> Smitty (9:169)
> al(9:184)
> et (9:181)

And the second note was the following:

> Examples with CPU (user + system) or elapsed time > 5s
>
> user system elapsed
>
> rp 4.832  0.176   5.009

For the first note, Smitty et al. is not a mispelling as its a paper that I am citing. I guess New Submission will also generate a note (is this a problem?).

The second note complains that my example takes longer than 5 second to run. Do all examples have to run in less than 5 seconds?

Any help on how to fix these NOTEs or how to re-submit such that it will pass the scrutiny of CRAN is much appreciated.

Comment: New submissions generate notes, nothing to worry about. The runtime of the examples, by contrast, is indeed a bit long — consider using smaller example datasets, or marking such examples as `\dontrun{}` or (specifically to get around the CRAN warning), `\donttest{}`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks. The runtime is due to the method being Bayesian MCMC method so the function inherently is a tad slow to run but is expected. I will try the \donttest{} as you suggest. Can you point me to any example documentation for how to implement the \donttest{} or is it as simple as placing in the begining of my example code the following: \donttest{ example code inside here }

Answer (score 1):

The first note is not a problem and is very unlikely be the reason for submission rejection. The second one however is likely to be a problem. Examples must run fast. You must reduce the amount of data used in the example or speed up your method, or reduce the number of examples.

Notice that `\donttest{}` is actually tested. But not always. I think it is tested when submitting but not during the other builds that are regularly triggered by the CRAN.